# How to set to row Background color for the ant design blazor table

Tags: blazor, antd, ant-blazor

I'm using my project for [ant design blazor table](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/table), anyone know how to adding background color for ant design blazor table row ,

**code here**

```
@using System.ComponentModel
@using AntDesign.TableModels

<Table TItem="Data" DataSource="@data" OnRowClick="OnRowClick">
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Name">
        <a>@context.Name</a>
    </Column>
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Age"></Column>
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Address">
        <TitleTemplate>
            <span> <Icon Type="environment" /> Address </span>
        </TitleTemplate>
    </Column>
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Tags">
        @foreach (var tag in context.Tags)
        {
            var color = tag.Length > 5 ? "geekblue" : "green";
            if (tag == "loser")
            {
                color = "volcano";
            }
            <Tag Color="@color">@tag</Tag>
        }
    </Column>
    <ActionColumn Title="Action">
        <Space Size=@("middle")>
            <SpaceItem>
                <a>Invite @context.Name</a>
            </SpaceItem>
            <SpaceItem>
                <a>Delete</a>
            </SpaceItem>
        </Space>
    </ActionColumn>
</Table>

@code{
    Data[] data = new Data[]
    {
        new()
        {
            Key = "1",
            Name = "John Brown",
            Age = 32,
            Address = "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
            Tags = new[] {"nice", "developer"}
        },
        new()
        {
            Key = "2",
            Name = "Jim Green",
            Age = 42,
            Address = "London No. 1 Lake Park",
            Tags = new[] { "loser"}
        },
        new()
        {
            Key = "3",
            Name = "Joe Black",
            Age = 32,
            Address = "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
            Tags = new[] { "cool", "teacher" }
        }
    };

    public class Data
    {
        [DisplayName("Key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tags")]
        public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    }

    void OnRowClick(RowData<Data> row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"row {row.Data.Key} was clicked.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way which I can think of is adding a `RowClassName` prop in the Antd blazor Table component,
and then add the styles for each row of the table.

You can add a className in rows of table in two ways.

1. Inline classname

```
<Table RowClassName="@(_=>"classname-for-row"> </Table>

<style> 
  .classname-for-row {
     background-color: blue;
  } 
</style>
// -----------------------------------------------------------
```

2. When you want to add classname for different rows based on some condition

```
<Table RowClassName="@(row => row.Data.RowClass"> </Table>
@code {
   public class Data
    {
       [DisplayName("Score")]
        public int Score { get; set; }

        public string RowClass => Score < 70 ? "danger" : "success";
    }
}
<style> 
  .danger {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .success {
    background-color: green:
  }
</style>
//-------------------------------------------------
```

Remember above showcases/examples is contrived.

Following is the complete example to add background colors for each row in the Antd blazor Table.

```
@using System.ComponentModel
@using AntDesign.TableModels

<Table TItem="Data" DataSource="@data" RowClassName="@(_=>"row-background")">
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Name">
        <a>@context.Name</a>
    </Column>
    <Column @bind-Field="@context.Score"></Column>
</Table>

<style>
    .row-background{
        background-color: #fff1f0;
    }
</style>

@code{
    Data[] data = new Data[]
    {
        new()
        {
            Key = "1",
            Name = "John Brown",
            Score = 95,
        },
        new()
        {
            Key = "2",
            Name = "Jim Green",
            Score = 87,
        }
        };

    public class Data
    {
        [DisplayName("Key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Score")]
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is also there in [antd Blazor documentation](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/table#components-table-demo-custom-row-style)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, its worked for me